# Field History tracking analysis

Tags: history-tracking, field-history

I am trying to provide some analysis to identify how times in a given time frame the account key fields changes. I know that there is a native sfdc report that provides you that information, however it’s not very user friendly and I want to export that information, summarize it, and provide the analysis to an internal manager. How can that be accomplished?

Comment: I say this all the time, excel 2013+ has an awesome extension called power query, you can query any object(assuming histories too) this extension supports custom domain too. Best part is you can refresh the data from the sheet / assuming u can schedule the refresh too.

Answer (score 0):

I am on excel 2010 :( 
I have thought about doing all the analysis in excel but struggling to think where to start. . I want to portray a story / picture.

For example this record has changed x amount of times and this field in particular changed x .

Comment: You may have to edit the question or post this as a comment, try to see if 2010 has the power query, alternate option is a tool like conga that you can use to creat merge links and combine multiple reports. A far as I see if you want to massage the data in excel then your options are to download hostory report and use native excel functions to do your analysis.